# Apache Spark: Update Output Mode After Join Operation on Streaming Datasets

Tags: apache-spark, join, group-by, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to write a code which does a join first and then does an aggregation (groupby and count).

I want the output of my aggregation stage to be updatable. Below is the code I use:

```
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._


    val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "testerIn")
      .load().selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]


    val interimDF = df.join(df,"value")

    val newDF = interimDF.groupBy("value").count().toJSON

    newDF.writeStream.format("kafka").outputMode("update") .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") . option("checkpointLocation","/path/to/directory")
      .option("topic", "tester").start()

    spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

This code throws an error because update mode isn't supported by stream-stream joins in spark:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Inner join between two streaming DataFrames/Datasets is not supported in Update output mode, only in Append output mode;;
```

Now, I understand completely why spark throws this error because when we are joining; update mode hardly makes any sense (because we'd just get a new row in the output whenever any new row comes in the input, hence append).

If I were to output the dataframe after my join (interimDF) to Kafka in append mode and then read from that and do my aggregation stage (newDF) and write it back in some other stream in update mode, my problem would be solved. That is exactly what I want to do, but I want to avoid the writing to Kafka stage in the middle. Is there any way this might be possible? I am also willing to accept hack-ish solutions or a link to a pull request someone may have made regarding similar stuff.

Comment: Similar issue. I am trying to do an aggregation followed by a join. This is apparently impossible because join queries support only Append and aggregation queries doesn't support Append.

Comment: I have since not worked on this. But if you want to collaborate I am more than certain we can make a patch for spark to make this possible.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not in a place to devote time toward this currently but I truly appreciate the offer.